# Horizontal stretching in ListRenderer

Tags: list, codenameone, renderer

I have a list that should display 7 items that each look like this:

```
Date      Weekday     Distance      Time

Long text that may span many lines

two column text       Distance      Time

two column text       Distance      Time

two column text       Distance      Time
```

The last lines repeat in a number depending on the data, i e there may be different amounts of such lines for each list item.

I have tried implementing this with a ListCellRenderer that creates a table according to the requirements above, but I have a few problems with it:

- The long text that may span many lines is implemented in a SpanLabel.  But this text will not display more than one line anyway
- Each item in the list will get space for the same number of lines below the first two..

So it seems that items in a list must be of the same size.

Later I also want to be able to detect selection on the entire list item, not just individual fields of it.

Is there a better way to do this?

How do I ensure that the SpanLabel actually gets as much space as it needs?

How do I ensure that the unknown number of lines gets the space they need, depending on how many they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a list: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/deeper-in-the-renderer.html

Lists in Codename One assume every entry is exactly the same height and provide no flexibility here.

I suggest doing something like the property cross demo: https://www.udemy.com/learn-mobile-programming-by-example-with-codename-one/

Where we use a `Container` with components within to provide a list like behavior with the full flexibility that arbitrary components allow.